# Electron: Send header origin with http request

Tags: angular, electron, http-post

I am converting my MEAN web app to a desktop app using Electron. Angular automatically sets the header origin when sending a POST request, but this is not happening on the desktop app. I tried to manually set the header, but it is not working. My code is,

```js
const headers = new HttpHeaders()
  .set('origin', 'www.google.com');
return this.http.post<any>(api_path, data, {'headers': headers});
```